# Android Run Process in Background

Tags: android, android-intentservice, android-broadcastreceiver

I am making an application that uses a BroadcastReceiver and a WakefulServiceIntent to call a method in my application every 10 minutes.  The problem is, sometimes it calls it, sometimes it doesn't.  I need to call this method every 10 minutes, even if the app is running in the background or the screen is off.  My current code is below.  Should I not be using an AlarmManager to start my timer?  I've heard that the AlarmManager isn't accurate, but so inaccurate to where it doesn't even go off?

AlarmManager starting code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), UpdateReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 0, intent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, (System.currentTimeMillis() + ((2 * 60) * 1000)), ((10 * 60) * 1000), pendingIntent);
```

BroadcastReceiver class:

```
public class UpdateReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent service = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);

        startWakefulService(context, service);

    }
```

}

WakefulIntentService class:

```
public class UpdateService extends IntentService {

    public UpdateService() {

        super("UpdateService");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        System.out.println("updated automatically");

        OverviewFragment.refresh(getApplicationContext());

        UpdateReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);

    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have quite a lot of experience developing background services and alarm-scheduled events on Samsung flagship smartphones.

You can try disabling battery optimizations for all your components but even then, the OS will not **reliably** call your code.

In my book, it is a bug, but I'm sure Samsung and/or Google consider it a feature (resource management is their absolutely top priority).